# How can i be sure a marionette view has been totally destroyed?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

When i call destroy on a marionette view and later try to use it throws an error saying it has been destroyed. Also when i remove the view from the DOM directly it also throws the same error. So i need to know how i can certain that the view is destroyed.

Comment: You usually get this error when trying to hold onto a view.  `region.show(new View())` will ensure that you never try to use a view that you've destroyed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `@JonathanMiles` is correct but I think some elaboration may help you and our Googlers.

You aptly mentioned two ways in which you may destroy a view.

1. Call `this.destroy()` on your view. The `.destroy()` method does several crucial things: 1. sets the `view.isDestroyed` bit so that Marionette can *know* that your view has been removed from the DOM; removes the view from the DOM and most bindings attached to it by calling `view.remove()` which eventually calls `view.$el.remove()`, and removes other bindings that `view.$el.remove()` does not (like Marionette `ui` elements and `behaviors`).
2. Simpy do `this.$el.remove()` on your view. This removes the HTML associated with the view from the DOM as well as events bound to that HTML, but not events that are created on cached HTML elements.

Now, with the first mentioned, it's obvious that Marionette will know that the view is destroyed. If you need to know whether the view is destroyed, like `@JonathanMiles` pointed out, simply obtain a reference to your view and check the value of `view.isDestroyed`.

But, if you decide to remove the view HTML from the DOM yourself, Marionette will *not* know if the view is not in the DOM. You may get errors, specifically since you may still have events bound to a view without HTML associated with it (although most of these situations would probably just pass silently unnoticed), but not from Marionette. Even worse, you may decide that to replace the rejected view, you'll spawn new views. The old view instance however will still live. While you won't have zombie events, this is a potential memory leak.

The moral of the story is don't simply do `view.$el.remove()`. Use Marionette's `view.destroy()` to completely free the view object for garbage collection, and reap the advantage of *knowing* if the view `.isDestroyed`.

Answer (score 6):

You can check whether a view has been destroyed or not using the view's `isDestroyed` property.

```
// Example
if (view.isDestroyed) {
    view = new View({});
}
view.doSomething();
```